# Reading excel files in python using dynamic dates in the file and sheet name

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, date

I have a situation in which I would want to read an excel file on a daily basis where the file name is written in the following format : `file_name 08.20.2018 xyz.xlsx` and gets updated daily where the date getting changed on a daily basis.

The same thing I need to do when this file is being read, I need to extract the data from a sheet whose naming convention also changes daily with the date. An example sheet name is `sheet1-08.20.2020-data`

How should I achieve this? I am using the following code but it does not work:

```
df = pd.read_Excel(r'file_name 08.20.2018 xyz.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1-08.20.2020-data')
```

how do I update this line of code so that it picks the data dynamically daily with new dates coming in. And to be clear here, the date will also be incremental with no gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `pathlib` and the `datetime` module to automate the process :

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import date

#assuming you have a directory of files:
folder = Path(directory of files)
sheetname = f"sheet1-0{date.today().month}.{date.today().day}.{date.today().year}-data"
date_string = f"filename 0{date.today().month}.{date.today().day}.{date.today().year}.xlsx"
xlsx_file = folder.glob(date_string)

#read in data
df = pd.read_excel(io=next(xlsx_file), sheet_name = sheetname)
```

Comment: getting the following error NameError: name 'Pathlib' is not defined. I have replaced from pathlib import Path to import pathlib. Still I am getting this error.

Comment: that's fine but now if I am running it again, I am facing a Stopiteration error while reading the excel file at this line df = pd.read_excel(io=next(xlsx_file), sheet_name = sheetname). I think I know the reason. My date is in form 08.20.2020 whereas the datae_String it is being read as 8.20.2020. How should I format this to make it similar? and also how could I fetch the previous date? like 08.19.2020?

Comment: if you look at the code I shared, you'll see I put a 0 in front of `date.today.month`, so it should not give you that error. You can check the output of date_string and see if it matches. Either ways, you'll have to tweak the code to meet your needs. For previous date, you could subtract 1 from date. The datetime module is your friend for that